# C# Getting an Error inserting data and image into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a column and image into a SQL Server 2008 database but i am getting 2 errors

> Error 1
>   The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.BinaryReader.BinaryReader(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments (line 62 column 35)
>
> Error 2
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'datagrid.FileStream' to 'System.IO.Stream'   (line 62  column 52)

I'm confused What to do ...

```
        try
        {
            byte[] img = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            string sql = "INSERT INTO PicTable(Name,Image) VALUES(" + textBox1.Text + ",@IMG)";
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", img));
            int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + " records saved.");
            conn.Close();

            pictEmp.Image = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: What kind of application is this? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors, FileStream is not coming from the System.IO namespace, it is coming from the dataGrid namespace.

Fully qualifying the FileStream should resolve your issue:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(picLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: na... not helping ... Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What type of data is picLoc?